# SQL selecting with multiple joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an example of database with three tables.

```
1 Work: workID, stateID, createddate

2 Work history table: workID, old_state, new_state, transitiondate

3 Work state: StateID; Statename
```

Let's say possible states are `1 = ready`, `2 = test` and `3 = approved`

I want to make query which would print list works and all of their state changes. The results should look something like this:

```
ID, createddate, Currentstate, OldState, Newstate, transitiondate
1,  1-1-2016,    approved,     ready,    test,     1-1-2016
1,  1-1-2016,    approved,     test,     approved, 2-1-2016
2,  1-5-2016,    test,         ready,    test,     1-5-2016
3,  1-10-2016,   approved,     ready,    test,     1-10-2016
3,  1-10-2016,   approved,     test,     approved, 1-15-2016 
...
```

I know how to make inner join so I can easily get the name of current state of the work from state table, but I can't get the names of old and new state. What sort of join commands I should use?

Comment: Join WorkState table twice; once for old state and once for new state.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query -

```
select t1.workID , t1.createddate , t3.Statename Currentstate ,
t4.Statename OldState , t5.Statename  Newstate, t2.transitiondate
from [Work] t1
join [Work history] t2 on t1.workID = t2.workID
join [state] t3  on t3.StateID = t1.stateID
join [state] t4  on t4.StateID = t2.old_state
join [state] t5  on t5.StateID = t2.new_state
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 3 inner joins to same table like below -

```
select 
w.workID as ID, 
W.createddate, 
WSC.Statename as Currentstate, 
WSO.Statename as OldState , 
WSN.Statename as Newstate, 
WH.transitiondate
from Work W
inner join workHistory WH on w.workID = WH.workID
inner join WorkState WSC on WSC.StateId = W.StateId
inner join WorkState WSO on WHO.StateId = WH.OldState
inner join WorkState WSN on WSN.StateId = WH.Newstate
```

OR

```
select 
w.workID as ID, 
W.createddate, 
(select top 1 Statename from WorkState where stateId = W.StateId) as Currentstate, 
(select top 1 Statename from WorkState where stateId = WH.OldState) as OldState , 
(select top 1 Statename from WorkState where stateId = WH.Newstate) as Newstate, 
WH.transitiondate
from Work W
inner join workHistory WH on w.workID = WH.workID
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Valtteri Vaahtonen,

you should consider using LEFT JOIN using the [Work history] table as your master table, and then link the other tables to it like this:

```
SELECT WH.ID, W.createddate, WS.Statename AS Currentstate, WH.OldState, WH.Newstate, WH.transitiondate 
FROM [Work history] WH 
LEFT JOIN [Work] W on WH.workID = W.workID
INNER JOIN [Work state] WS ON WS.StateID = W.StateID
```

Let me know if it helps!